# Ethernet adapter not in connections of Server with KDE

Tags: networking, drivers, server, kde, ethernet

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 18.04, then added Kubuntu's GUI for a lightweight GUI on the front end node of my new cluster project.

I have two wireless adapters and one Ethernet. I'm only connected to the Internet (updates, etc) via Ethernet now, but the only connection visible in the settings is the wireless adapter. Therefore I cannot see the Ethernet hardware to configure the IP, gateway, netmask, and other settings  to listen for my nodes and use the WiFi for the Internet.

How may I configure my network settings?

Answer (score 1):

`ip address show` in a Terminal window will show you what you need. For more on [ip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ip.8.html), see its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ip.8.html).

Or, to do it the GUI way, right click on the empty area in the System Tray -> **system tray settings** -> click **Network Managemen**t .

If you can't find Network Management, install it with `sudo snap install network-manager` and then learn it at https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/